# How to get the event handler when grid is filtered in client side in Kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have create a simple grid here and I want to recalculate the sum of a column when the grid is filtered locally. I do not want to have calculated column or template since I want to update a label and as well I have to do some other actions in the page when grid is filtered locally.

```
var data = [
    { item: "item1", weight: 15 },
    { item: "item2", weight: 22 },
    { item: "item3", weight: 43 },
    { item: "item4", weight: 37 },
    { item: "item5", weight: 33 }
];
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        { field: "item" },
        { field: "weight" }
    ],
    filterable: true,                       
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    resizable:true, 
    selectable: "row",
    columnMenu: true,
    dataSource:data ,
    change: function(e) {
        var grid = e.sender;
        var selected = grid.dataItem(this.select());
        alert(selected.item);
        getSum();
    }
});
getSum();
function getSum() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    var sum = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i<= (data.length-1);i++)
    {
        sum = sum + data[i].weight;    
    }
    $("#weight-label").text(sum);   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KendoDev/gb3qzgm2/

How to get the event handler when grid is filtered in client side?

Comment: Did you try the `dataBinding` or `dataBound` event hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function that computes the sum, you should use `grid.dataSource.view()` instead of `grid.dataSource.data()`.

Your JSFiddle modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/gb3qzgm2/1/

According Kendo UI documentation: `data()`

> Returns Gets the data items of the data source.

whereas `view()`

> Returns the data items which correspond to the current page, filter, sort and group configuration

Then, if you want to automatically update the label, you might invoke `getSum` from the grid `dataBound` event handler as in this other version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/gb3qzgm2/2/

Comment: OnaBai, filter is not at all working now, what went wrong? I am confused.

Comment: What do you mean that it is not working on? Which filtering condition are you trying to set? Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/gb3qzgm2/5/

Comment: Yes, some how I forgot the model definition in data source. now it works, thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

I only made a couple of minor changes to your code, these changes accommodate the way Kendo mandates when we can inject our own custom javascript before it generates the "Kendo revised/generated" javascript string:

http://jsfiddle.net/gb3qzgm2/4/

```
var data = [{
    item: "item1",
    weight: 15
}, {
    item: "item2",
    weight: 22
}, {
    item: "item3",
    weight: 43
}, {
    item: "item4",
    weight: 37
}, {
    item: "item5",
    weight: 33
}];
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "item"
    }, {
        field: "weight"
    }],
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    resizable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    columnMenu: true,
    dataSource: data,
    change: function (e) {
        var grid = e.sender;
        var selected = grid.dataItem(this.select());
        alert(selected.item);
        var s = getSum();

        $("#weight-label, .k-pager-info").text('The Sum is: ' + s);
    }
});
//getSum();

function getSum() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= (data.length - 1); i++) {
        sum = sum + data[i].weight
    }
    return sum
}
```

Comment: This will not be the answer, because it will not work here, http://jsfiddle.net/KendoDev/gb3qzgm2/6/

Comment: You're right, in that fiddle, the changes I made only run/fix your code when a user clicks on a grid element, and that was not your question, you were/are looking to hook into the filter lifecycle and @OnaBai is right to offer up `grid.dataSource.view()` as the solution.